# tableview data doesn't display after dismissing modal view and no data changed

Tags: ios, uitableview

from a tableview controller, I display a modal view to capture a video clip...
upon cancel ( no clip shot) the image picker is dismissed ,and the tableview is redisplayed but with a black screen... seems not being populated anymore ... what am I missing ?

```
//  MySwingsViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Swing.h"
#import "SwingCell.h"

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface MySwingsViewController : UITableViewController  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate >

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *swings;

@property (copy,   nonatomic) NSURL *movieURL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *movieController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *captureSwingbutton;
- (IBAction)captureSwing:(id)sender;

@end
```

and the MySwingsViewController.m

```
//  MySwingsViewController.m
#import "MySwingsViewController.h"

@interface MySwingsViewController ()
@end

@implementation MySwingsViewController

{
    NSArray *tableData; //just for test purposes
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"view did load");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize table data
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SwingCell";
 SwingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
 if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[SwingCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
cell.titleLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (IBAction)captureSwing:(id)sender {
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.allowsEditing = NO;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    ...  // capture new clip
  }
 ...
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
   NSLog(@"picker did cancel");
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

cancel is logged, picker is dismissed, back to tableview , but data are not redisplayed...

Answer (score 0):

Don't call [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; this code actually dismissing the current MySwingsViewController and I believe your table view is on the MySwingsViewController right?

Comment: yes..it is, removed it , but doesn't solve the issue, the table view is displayed wo any data